# Python Dict overwrite previous list

Tags: python

```
Temp = {}
Final = {}

OK =['OK','OK']
NOTOK =['NOTOK','NOTOK']

Temp[1] = OK
Final['u1']=Temp

print(Final)

Temp.clear()
Temp[2] = OK
Final['u2']=Temp

print(Final)

Temp.clear()
Temp[3] = NOTOK
Final['u3']=Temp

print(Final)
```

would like to know why last print out overwrite previous one, need help.
it related to my current project, this is i use simplfy term, how to make u3 dict(NOTOK) not replacing u1 and u2 content(OK).

Actual result

```
{'u1': {1: ['OK', 'OK']}}
{'u1': {2: ['OK', 'OK']}, 'u2': {2: ['OK', 'OK']}}
{'u1': {3: ['NOTOK', 'NOTOK']}, 'u2': {3: ['NOTOK', 'NOTOK']}, 'u3': {3: ['NOTOK', 'NOTOK']}}
```

Expected result

```
{'u1': {1: ['OK', 'OK']}}
{'u1': {2: ['OK', 'OK']}, 'u2': {2: ['OK', 'OK']}}
{'u1': {3: ['OK', 'OK']}, 'u2': {3: ['OK', 'OK']}, 'u3': {3: ['NOTOK', 'NOTOK']}}
```

Comment: `Final['u1'] = Temp.copy()`, `Final['u2'] = Temp.copy()`, `Final['u3'] = Temp.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `.copy()`

```
Temp = {}
Final = {}

OK =['OK','OK']
NOTOK =['NOTOK','NOTOK']

Temp[1] = OK.copy()
Final['u1']=Temp.copy()

print(Final)

Temp.clear()
Temp[2] = OK.copy()
Final['u2']=Temp.copy()

print(Final)

Temp.clear()
Temp[3] = NOTOK.copy()
Final['u3']=Temp.copy()

print(Final)
```